# How do I get the first page number of the currect chapter/section?

Tags: luatex, chapters

I would like to get

1. the page number of the first page of the current chapter
2. the page number of the first page of the current section

Is it possible?

The goal is to add the chapter/section to a secondary toc, but currectly I get the actual page instead of the page number of the first page of the current chapter

```
\addcontentsline{todo}{section}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thesection}{\Sectionname}}%
```

**EDIT** I will not maintain the labels for chapter and section.
Further, the whole thing has to be automatic, that is the program does not know if it has to use the label `sec:function` or `sec:relation`; and I do not want to define label of the form `sec:1:3`.

**EDIT 2** One way would be to modify the `chapter` command in order to save the page number in a variable (I do not know how!), but perhaps there is a more clean way.

Comment: Use the built in label/ref-mechanism.

Comment: @Johannes_B thank you for the comment. I forgot to say that I do not want to maintain the labels. I edit the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine `\chapter` and `\section` to issue a suitable `\label` command, that's automatically built from a counter that's stepped at each `\chapter` or `\section` command.

The label can be stored in the commands `\currentchapterlabel` and `\currentsectionlabel` that any `\chapter` or `\section` command will override.

Finally, we can define `\currentchapterpage` and `\currentsectionpage` to do the suitable `\pageref` command.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcounter{currentchaptersection}
\renewcommand{\thecurrentchaptersection}{\roman{currentchaptersection}}
\let\latexchapter\chapter
\let\latexsection\section

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \stepcounter{currentchaptersection}%
  \xdef\currentchapterlabel{css-\thecurrentchaptersection}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexchapter*{#3}}
    {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}\label{\currentchapterlabel}}%
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \stepcounter{currentchaptersection}%
  \xdef\currentsectionlabel{css-\thecurrentchaptersection}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexsection*{#3}}
    {\latexsection[#2]{#3}\label{\currentsectionlabel}}%
}

\newcommand{\currentchapterpage}{\pageref{\currentchapterlabel}}
\newcommand{\currentsectionpage}{\pageref{\currentsectionlabel}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\kant[1-5]

\section{Two}

\kant[6-19]

This chapter started on page~\currentchapterpage.

This section started on page~\currentsectionpage.


\section{Three}

\kant[6-19]

This chapter started on page~\currentchapterpage.

This section started on page~\currentsectionpage.


\chapter{Four}

\kant[1-5]

\section{Five}

\kant[6-19]

This chapter started on page~\currentchapterpage.

This section started on page~\currentsectionpage.

\section{Six}

\kant[6-19]

This chapter started on page~\currentchapterpage.

This section started on page~\currentsectionpage.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Straightforward and clear. Due to the lack of `expl`-style spacing in the code, though, I almost believed that you had placed the `\label` commands inside the mandatory argument of `\latexchapter` or `\latexsection`. ;-)

Comment: The output works, but the compilation gives me a bunch of errors of the type: https://imgur.com/69aAqOq

Comment: @PeptideChain You probably have an outdated version of xparse.

Comment: I confirm. And overleaf.com has also an old version.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcounter{pgnumchapter}
\setcounter{pgnumchapter}{0}
\newcounter{pgnumsection}
\setcounter{pgnumsection}{0}
\xapptocmd{\chaptermark}{%
  \setcounter{pgnumchapter}{\thepage}%
}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xapptocmd{\sectionmark}{%
  \setcounter{pgnumsection}{\thepage}%
}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ch1}
\section{Introduction}
First page
\vfill
\pagebreak
\section{Conclusion}
Second page
\vfill
\pagebreak
Third page

First page chapter: \thepgnumchapter.

First page section: \thepgnumsection.

Current page: \thepage.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, unfortunately I believe it doesn't work for unnumbered chapters or sections (as they don't do `\chaptermark` resp. `\sectionmark`).

Comment: @frougon Thank you for the comment. Probably I will never need it, because the whole thing is for a to do list, and I do not have appendix (just an empty preface). If you like a challenge: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499192