# Manipulating page number in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, luatex

I would like to add a new line to the toc, **but** with full control of the page number on the right. That is, in the following picture I would like a 17 instead of a 5.

[image]

Below is my attempt, that I do not understand why it does not work.

> That is, I would like a solution, but also to understand why my code does not work.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{ch1}
\chapter{ch2}

\newcounter{tmp}
\setcounter{tmp}{\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{17}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{blah blah}
\setcounter{page}{\thetmp}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\addcontentsline` is not written directly to the toc/aux but only when the page is shipped out. At this moment you have already reset the counter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{ch1}
\chapter{ch2}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}{blah blah}{17}{}}

\end{document}
```