# How to reset counter when meet section*?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am trying to reset the counter every time meet a `section` based on this [doc](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Counters).

```
\documentclass{article} 

\newcounter{example}[section]  % This line reset the counter every time meet a section
\newenvironment{example}[1][]
{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \subsection*{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}
{\medskip}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\begin{example}
A
\end{example}

\begin{example}
B
\end{example}

\section{Another section}

\begin{example}
C
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

This will generate

[image]

which means it works.

However, now I want to remove the number before section, so I added `*` after `section`.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\newcounter{example}[section]  % Tried to change `section*`, but throws error
\newenvironment{example}[1][]
{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \subsection*{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}
{\medskip}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}

\begin{example}
A
\end{example}

\begin{example}
B
\end{example}

\section*{Another section}

\begin{example}
C 
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

However, this time, the counter won't reset like

[image]

If I changed to

```
\newcounter{example}[section*]
```

It will throw error

> No counter 'section*' defined.

How to reset counter when meet `section*`?

Comment: `\section*{...}\setcounter{example}{0}`

Comment: @Fran that is a nice workaround way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got an error with `\newcounter{example}[section*]` because `section*` is not a counter in LaTeX. `section` is, but not `section*`.

## First method: patching `\@startsection`

You can patch `\@startsection` so that when `\section*` is called (which is a sectioning command of level 1) and only in this case, your `example` counter is reset to 0. The following works because `\@ssect` is only called for unnumbered sectioning commands, and we only reset the counter when the level of the sectioning command is 1 (`\section` or `\section*`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]
  {\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \subsection*{Example~\theexample. #1}%
   \rmfamily}
  {\medskip}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@startsection}
  {\@ssect}{\ifnum#2=1 \setcounter{example}{0}\fi\@ssect}
  {}{\FAILED}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}

\begin{example}
A
\end{example}

\begin{example}
B
\end{example}

\section*{Another section}

\begin{example}
C
\end{example}

\begin{example}
D
\end{example}

\section{Numbered section}

\begin{example}
E
\end{example}

\begin{example}
F
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

## Second method: using `xparse` to redefine `\section`

Another way to achieve the same result is to use `xparse` in order to redefine `\section`, as egreg did in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499132/73317). The advantage of this technique is that it doesn't rely on implementation details of `\section` and `\@startsection`, therefore it should always work even if `\section` has been redefined and is not LaTeX2e's `\section` command anymore—this may be the case if you redefine `\section` using a package such as `titlesec`, or simply if you try to pile up several redefinitions done with the first technique. Thus, I would say that this second method is better from an engineering point of view.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]
  {\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \subsection*{Example~\theexample. #1}%
   \rmfamily}
  {\medskip}

% Save the original \section command
\let\latexsection\section

% Simple redefinition of \section (including \section*)
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\setcounter{example}{0}%
     \latexsection*{#3}}
    {\latexsection[#2]{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}

\begin{example}
A
\end{example}

\begin{example}
B
\end{example}

\section*{Another section}

\begin{example}
C
\end{example}

\begin{example}
D
\end{example}

\section{Numbered section}

\begin{example}
E
\end{example}

\begin{example}
F
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Both techniques lead to the following output:

[image: Screenshot]

## Remarks on implementation of user-defined environments

In your real environment, you may want to do something like this (or a variant) in order to be sure that your input doesn't introduce unwanted spaces. This is a general remark regarding user-defined environments; since `\subsection*` typically starts a new paragraph—unless you are using the *run-in* layout type—the `\ignorespaces` is probably not needed here, for example. Similarly, `\ignorespacesafterend` shouldn't be necessary after `\par\medskip`, since `\par` puts TeX in vertical mode where spaces are ignored—but it shouldn't harm, nevertheless.

```latex
\newenvironment{example}[1][]
  {\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \subsection*{Example~\theexample. #1}%
   \rmfamily
   \ignorespaces}
  {\unskip
   \par\medskip
   \ignorespacesafterend}
```