# Adding numberless chapters to the table of contents with titlesec

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc

How to add numberless chapters to the table of contents with `titlesec` avoiding `\addcontentsline` after `\chapter`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}


\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\huge}
 {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
 {1ex}
 {}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{xx}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{xy}

\chapter{xy}

\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What kind of solution do you have in mind? Since ... You know what to do.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc *might* be of help

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `\chapter` using `xparse`, a bit like in [this answer of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499132/73317). Note that I only do the redefinition after `\tableofcontents` has been used, otherwise you would see “Contents” twice in a row, since the `\tableofcontents` is introduced as a `\chapter*` (`\tableofcontents` would add its own title to the table of contents).

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape]{geometry} % small page size for the screenshot
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc,xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\huge}
 {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
 {1ex}
 {}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}

\let\latexchapter\chapter

\newcommand*{\redefineChapter}{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{ s O{##3} m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}
      {\latexchapter*{##3}%
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{##2}}
      {\latexchapter[##2]{##3}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\redefineChapter

\chapter*{An unnumbered chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{A numbered chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With this code, you can even use `\chapter*` with an optional argument in order to specify a special variant of the title for the table of contents:

```latex
\chapter*[Title in the toc]{An unnumbered chapter}
```

[image]