# How to automatically add a mark showing that the section is continued on the next page?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically set a symbol (eg. `►`) somewhere at the end of an odd page every time a section is being continued on the following even page?

Manually this could be done by putting eg. `\vfill\hfill$\triangleright$` after the last line of the odd page. But that doesn't work when the bottom line is full. And it's still no solution for a long document. And no solution at all when page breaks might still move.

So I thought maybe of something like a mark that appears next to the page number, something like this red triangle here:
[image: exemplary mark]

Any idea how to create this?

Here's an MWE in which I left all the packages I am using in my document, in order to early recognize any conflicts.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,titlepage,headsepline,headings=small,BCOR=8mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese,polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[columns=2,itemlayout=abshang,initsep=1.8em plus 0.2em minus 0.2em]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\KOMAoptions{paper=24cm:17cm,DIV=14}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex plus 0.8ex minus 0.4ex}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{0.4cm}
\addtolength{\headsep}{-0.4cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.2cm}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip}}

\preto{\addsec}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}
\hfuzz=2pt
\flushbottom

\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\ohead[]{\sffamily\leftmark}
\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[]{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
        \ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
        \raggedbottom
\chapter{Chapter}       
\addsec{Section 1}
    \lipsum[5]  
    \lipsum[4]  
\addsec{Section 2}
    \lipsum[4]  
\addsec{Section 3}
    \lipsum[8]  
    \lipsum[6]  
\addsec{Section 4}
    \lipsum[3]  
    \lipsum[8]  
    \lipsum[7]  
\addsec{Section 5}
    \lipsum[4]  
    \lipsum[3]  
    \lipsum[2]  
\addsec{Section 6}
    \lipsum[8]  
    \lipsum[8]  
    \lipsum[1]  
\addsec{Section 7}
    \lipsum[9]  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do the same, searched for days and finally came up with a solution that might work for most cases (I haven't tested exhaustively, please double check for every page and write a comment if something looks wrong).

So we want a way to find out if a section continues to the next page and, if so, add a special mark, like this:

[image]

My solution is based on adding a different footnote depending if it is at the end of a section, and the trick is: we check, at the time the footnote is being made, whether the current section starts in a page that is ahead of the page being printed:

- If the current section starts on a page that is greater than the page being printed, that means that we just started a new section, and it'll be printed on the next page (the current one is full). In this case, we don't add the mark.
- If the current section has started on a previous page or in the current page, this means the current section will continue on the next page (otherwise, we would have a new section before the page break). In this case, we print the mark.

In order to do this, I set a counter to keep the starting page of the current section, as suggested by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499132/114310).

Here's how it goes:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm, paperheight=18cm, top=2.2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.6cm, right=1.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Allow to get the start page of current section
\newcounter{currentsection}
\renewcommand{\thecurrentsection}{\roman{currentsection}}
\let\latexsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \stepcounter{currentsection}%
  \xdef\currentsectionlabel{css-\thecurrentsection}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexsection*{#3}}
    {\latexsection[#2]{#3}\label{\currentsectionlabel}}%
}
\newcommand{\currentsectionpage}{\pageref{\currentsectionlabel}}

% Configure footnote
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot[R]{ % If you have 'twoside' and only want it in the odd pages, change R to RO.
    \ifthenelse{\thepage<\currentsectionpage}{}{\bf continued $\triangleright$}}


\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Title}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Title}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Title}
\lipsum[1-4]

\fancyfoot[R]{} % Never print 'continued' on last page

\end{document}
```

Important: remember you may **need to compile it twice** so the page references are calculated correctly.